# Tensorboxes in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tensor

I have the problem that I can only determine the number of boxes in the x and y direction once using the sliders. As soon as I switch the slider again, it reacts, but the number of boxes is not changed again. The list with the positions of the boxes "pl" is not updated as well as xSlider and ySlider Thanks for your answer (if there are any questions about my code let me know :-) )

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox
from matplotlib.artist import Artist
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# axes not visilble
ax.set_visible( False)

### list

# position of tensorbox list
pl = []

# list position x y
xl = 0
yl = 0

# intermediate variable
pos = 0

### position variable

# start value parameter(amount of parameters) function (amount fo functions) / chanches are posible but it will change the sice of the tensorboxes
x = 9
y = 9

# start nummber of tensorboxes in x and y diraction
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(int(y),int(x))

# space for the tensorboxes
gs.update(left=0.2, right=0.9, bottom=0.15, top=0.80, hspace=0.1,)

# order of tensorboxes and plot tensorboxes
axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[i,j]) for i,j in [[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],]]

# axes of tensorbexes not visible
for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.tick_params(bottom=False, labelbottom=False, left=False, labelleft=False)
    
#//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Slider

x = 0
y = 0


# Define the sliders and slider position parameter function
ax_x = plt.axes([0.425, 0.90, 0.20, 0.03],)
ax_y = plt.axes([0.425, 0.85, 0.20, 0.03],)

# Define Slider value a1 b1 c1
xSlider = Slider(ax_x, 'Parameter anzahl', 1.0, 8.0, valinit=x, valstep=1)
ySlider = Slider(ax_y, 'Funktionen anzahl', 1.0, 8.0, valinit=y, valstep=1)

#//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////update variable list

# x update x
def update_x(xSlider):
    global x
    x = xSlider - 1
    print("x", x)
    print("y", y)

# y update y
def update_y(ySlider):
    global y
    y = ySlider - 1
    print("x", x)
    print("y", y)

# x y update pl
def update_pl(null):
    global xl
    global yl
    global x
    global y
    global pl
    xl = 0
    yl = 0
    #clear the list
    pl.clear()
    while xl <= x:
        while yl <= y:
            pos = [yl,xl]
            pl.append(pos)
            yl = yl + 1
        xl = xl + 1
        yl = 0
    print(pl)
          
def update_gs(null):
    global x
    global y
    global gs
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(y,x)

# pl update axes
def update_axes(null):
    global xSlider
    global ySlider
    global axes
    global pl
    plt.clf()
    axes = 0
    #Artist.remove(axes)
    axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[i,j]) for i,j in pl]
    for ax in fig.get_axes():
        ax.tick_params(bottom=False, labelbottom=False, left=False, labelleft=False)
    ax_x = plt.axes([0.425, 0.90, 0.20, 0.03],)
    ax_y = plt.axes([0.425, 0.85, 0.20, 0.03],)
    xSlidernew = Slider(ax_x, 'Parameter anzahl', 1.0, 8.0, valinit=x, valstep=1)
    ySlidernew = Slider(ax_y, 'Funktionen anzahl', 1.0, 8.0, valinit=y, valstep=1)
    xSlider = xSlidernew
    ySlider = ySlidernew
    

#//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////update Slider

### update value

# x y Slider on changed x y
xSlider.on_changed(update_x)
ySlider.on_changed(update_y)

# x y Slider on changed pl
xSlider.on_changed(update_pl)
ySlider.on_changed(update_pl)

# x y Slider on changed gs
xSlider.on_changed(update_gs)
ySlider.on_changed(update_gs)

# x y Slider on changed axes
xSlider.on_changed(update_axes)
ySlider.on_changed(update_axes)

#//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
plt.show()
```